# Rendering a generic file field containing an image

Tags: 7, media, files, entities

```
Drupal 7.34
Media 7.x-1.4
Views 7.x-3.8
```

I have a generic file field. Sometimes the uploaded file is an image, and in these cases I want to render it in a View as a thumbnail.

So I do the following:

> - Go to `admin/config/media/file-types`
> - Choose "manage file display" next to Image
>
>   - Pick a View Mode, let's say "Small"
>   - Check the box next to the Image display
>   - Pick my desired Image style from the dropdown in the display settings
> - Add the file field to my View
>
>   - Choose "Rendered file" formatter
>   - Choose "Small" view mode
>   - hit Apply

…and the view puts a big blank space where the image should be.

I've checked the database, and Drupal has correctly identified my upload as image/jpeg. It opens fine in the browser.

If I choose a different formatter in the view, like Table of files or Generic file, it shows up fine.

If I choose a different formatter in the file display settings, it still shows nothing in the view.

Am I misunderstanding something? What's going on?

Comment: In your display precedence order, is 'Image' first (if it's not the only enabled display)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `admin/config/media/file-types/manage/image/display/media_small` and check that File is actually being displayed and not set hidden.

Comment: THAT WAS IT, thank you so much! Grief, why would a display mode be set to show absolutely nothing by *default*?